# Rejoin specific splitted strings in a list PYTHON

Tags: python, split

I have a listing containing values with measurement unit and i want to remove them, the original list is mentioned below:

```
['Dawn:', 'Sunrise:', 'Moonrise:', 'Dusk:', 'Sunset:\xa0', 'Moonset:', 'Daylight:', 'Length:', 'Phase:', 'Temperature', 'Dew\xa0Point ', 'Windchill', 'Humidity', 'Heat Index', 'Apparent Temperature', 'Solar Radiation', 'Evapotranspiration Today', 'Rainfall\xa0Today', 'Rainfall\xa0Rate', 'Rainfall\xa0This\xa0Month', 'Rainfall\xa0This\xa0Year', 'Rainfall\xa0Last Hour', 'Last rainfall', 'Wind\xa0Speed\xa0(gust)', 'Wind\xa0Speed\xa0(avg)', 'Wind Bearing', 'Beaufort\xa0F1', 'Barometer\xa0', 'Rising slowly']
['07:30', '08:04', '17:03', '19:05', '18:31', '01:45', '11:35', '10:27', 'Waxing Gibbous', '13.7\xa0°C', '11.4\xa0°C', '13.7\xa0°C', '86%', '13.7\xa0°C', '13.0\xa0°C', '0\xa0W/m²', '0.15\xa0mm', '0.0\xa0mm', '0.0\xa0mm/hr', '36.4\xa0mm', '36.4\xa0mm', '0.0\xa0mm', '2018-10-14 08:52', '6.1\xa0kts', '2.6\xa0kts', '229° SW', 'Light air', '1026.89\xa0mb', '0.27\xa0mb/hr']
```

To remove measurement units like degrees, kts, mb etc. i follow the below approach:

```
    newlist = [word for line in test for word in line.split()]
    #print(newlist)
    testlist = ['°C', 'W/m²', 'mm','mm/hr', 'mb','kts', 'mb/hr', '%']
    t = [x for x in newlist for d in testlist if d in x]

    s = [r for r in newlist if r not in testlist]
```

After this code, i am able to remove all units, but then values which are strings and are separated by spaces like **Waxing Gibbous** becomes comma separated. is there possible i join them back with spaces?

Result of code:

```
['Dawn:', 'Sunrise:', 'Moonrise:', 'Dusk:', 'Sunset:\xa0', 'Moonset:', 'Daylight:', 'Length:', 'Phase:', 'Temperature', 'Dew\xa0Point ', 'Windchill', 'Humidity', 'Heat Index', 'Apparent Temperature', 'Solar Radiation', 'Evapotranspiration Today', 'Rainfall\xa0Today', 'Rainfall\xa0Rate', 'Rainfall\xa0This\xa0Month', 'Rainfall\xa0This\xa0Year', 'Rainfall\xa0Last Hour', 'Last rainfall', 'Wind\xa0Speed\xa0(gust)', 'Wind\xa0Speed\xa0(avg)', 'Wind Bearing', 'Beaufort\xa0F1', 'Barometer\xa0', 'Rising slowly']
['07:30', '08:04', '17:03', '19:05', '18:31', '01:45', '11:35', '10:27', 'Waxing', 'Gibbous', '13.7', '11.4', '13.7', '86%', '13.7', '13.0', '0', '0.15', '0.0', '0.0', '36.4', '36.4', '0.0', '2018-10-14', '08:52', '5.2', '2.4', '188°', 'S', 'Light', 'air', '1026.21', '0.23']
```

Main source code from where data is being fetched:

[Data origin source code](https://codeshare.io/GLvjVV)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: I have a feeling this is not a minimal example . can you extract an actual list of values you can't join back?

Comment: I am sorry i didn't get your point ?

Comment: A lot of this code does not have anything to do with joining lists.  Just post the lists instead of the whole program.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: ok, let me edit my question

Comment: @ChristianSloper i hope question is a bit clearer now

Comment: @tangoal i got it and followed what he said and there is no point to repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your source data identified earlier is from a dict called grouped (think if you could put that back in and show an example that be great)

From group you want to get all the keys as headers and values as values but replacing all the symbols you do not need.

The code below does that for you starting from your grouped dict and stores your header and value into 2 seperate list:

```
headers = []
values = []
testlist = ['°C', 'W/m²', 'mm','mm/hr', 'mb','kts', 'mb/hr']

for i in a[0]:
    for k,v in i.items():
        headers.append(k)
        values.append(v)

for idx,v in enumerate(values):
    for t in testlist:
        values[idx] = values[idx].replace(t,'')

for h,v in zip(headers,values):
    print('Header: {} , Value : {}'.format(h,v))
```

It definitely is helpful in the future if you outline where your source data begins and then your expected output.

Comment: You are right, i tried this approach but then they do not remain comma separated because afterwards i need to write them to csv

Comment: Maybe show us your expected results? You can add a comma to your string if you want it to have comma separation.

Comment: i have edited my post, please check. you are right again but then will also add comma to string which are suppose to be separated by space. For example, see below Waxing Gibbous which also gets separated by comma
`07:30,08:04,17:03,19:05,18:31,01:45,11:35,10:27,Waxing,Gibbous,13.7,11.4,13.7,86%,13.7,13.0,0,0.15,0.0,0.0,36.4,36.4,0.0,2018-10-14,08:52,7.0,2.7,233°,SW,Light,air,1026.86,0.28`

Comment: That is because you are using split to replace values. Give me a second.

Comment: Edited answer. In order not to hardcode it, you need to get the original dict values from grouped and not change it with split.

Comment: Thank you BernardL